# reading line of a file into a linked list

Tags: c

Reading a file into a linked list, where every node stores a single line of text. Currently the output for every node is the same (first) line of text. The problem must be that I am still referring to the *old* line buffer during the while loop, but I can not see why. for an input file with three lines:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I get the output:

```
line1

line1

line1
```

The spaces, do not concern me, code as follows.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
  char* line;
  struct node* next;
} Node ;

#define MAXLINESIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  char* filePath = argv[2] ;
  FILE* handle = fopen(filePath, "r") ;

  char* linebuffer = malloc(MAXLINESIZE);
  //  char linebuffer[MAXLINESIZE];
  Node* root = malloc(sizeof(Node));
  Node* node = root;

  while (fgets(linebuffer,MAXLINESIZE,handle) != NULL) {
    node->line = linebuffer;
    node->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node = node->next;
    char* linebuffer = malloc(MAXLINESIZE);
    // char linebuffer[MAXLINESIZE];
  }

  puts(root->line); // outputs first line, fine
  puts(root->next->line);
  puts(root->next->next->line); // this is still pointing to the first line buffer

  fclose(handle) ;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is where you allocate a new `linebuffer` in the loop; because you *declare* a new variable named `linebuffer`, the `linebuffer` being assigned to `node->line` is the first one.

Remove the `char*` from the line in the loop where you allocate `linebuffer`, so it refers to the one declared outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the control expression of this loop ...

```
while (fgets(linebuffer,MAXLINESIZE,handle) != NULL) {
    node->line = linebuffer;
    node->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node = node->next;
    char* linebuffer = malloc(MAXLINESIZE);
    // char linebuffer[MAXLINESIZE];
}
```

... you are reading the data into dynamically allocated array `linebuffer`.  That's fine.

In the loop body, however, you declare a *new* variable `linebuffer` that shadows the one used in the control expression.  You allocate a new buffer and assign a pointer to it to that inner-scope variable, but that does not change the shadowed variable.  As a result, on the next iteration you read any new data into the same buffer as on the previous iteration.  And you leak memory.